# Is this set a submanifold and how could i show it ? Trigonometric functions.

Tags: manifolds, submanifold

I want to demonstrate the set :

$$\left\{(\cosh(x),\cosh(x)\tan(y),x),(x,y)\in \left]-3,3 \right[\times\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left] \frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \right[ \right\}$$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If it makes sense , how can i prove it ? Otherwise , why is it not a submanifold ?

I have thought about defining a mapping :

$\phi$ : $\left]-3,3 \right[\times\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left] \frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \right[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,(x,y)\rightarrow (\cosh(x),\cosh(x)\tan(y),x)$ and maybe try to play with the fact submanifolds of $\mathbb{R^n}$ are it's opened set , but there's no way this can properly define a homeomorphism i believe,

Update: Thanks to Didier for his contribution :
The still unsolved problem can also be reformulated using the periodicity of tan function as demonstrate the set :

$$\left\{(\cosh(x),\cosh(x)\tan(y),x),(x,y)\in \left]-3,3 \right[\times\left] \frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right[ \right\}$$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if this makes sense.

Comment: Note that $\tan$ is periodic, thus you can restric the $y$ value to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. This should be easier to handle.

Comment: I'm not really at ease with the notion of submanifold in the sense that the abstract definition is not really visual to me and i'm not really convinced that : if the restriction on such a $\pi$ size interval of $y$ makes the latter set a submanifold , then the "entire" set is a submanifold.

Comment: What I said is just that your parametrization is redundant: some points are infinitely many times defined because of periodicity of $\tan$. It is the same thing as saying $[-1,1] = \{ \cos(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ \cos(x) \mid x \in [-\pi,\pi]\}$: the set is not changed, but the parametrization is easier to handle. Being a submanifold is a property of the set, not of how you describe it.

Comment: Yes sorry , end of day. That may surely help me tomorrow when i'll try again ,at least it gives a simpler visual for the problem.